# SQLite identify missing index

Tags: sqlite, indexing, identify

Could you tell me please if it is possible to identify missing indexes for a select query using SQLite database?

Or is there any tool that can help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) command to identify missing index for given SQL query. For example, the following result indicates you may need an index for a in table t1.

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT a, b FROM t1 WHERE a=1;
SCAN TABLE t1
```

If you have a lot of SQL queries and want to quickly identify missing index, I wrote a [tool](https://github.com/RodChen/analyze-sqlite-index) which helps analyze many SQL queries and saves you much time in the repeating process.

Answer (score 1):

Using the sqlite3 command line tool, first enter

```
.expert
```

And then run your query as normal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).